# REACT.JS - how to update multiple children on parents state change by one of children

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am struggling for a few days with React, and all the tutorials saying how magnificent it is make me feel that somebody is tricking me :) Learning curve especially while i need to comunicate children-parent-children is so annoying! Anyways...

Consider such a situation:
I have multiple buttons. Each button has its own type. There may be mutiple buttons with one type making a group. Whole idea is to have buttons enabling other buttons, and disabling other ones. 
I provide pen to see working example, however imagine i have buttons of types:

- settingsOn - it enables all the buttons of type *settings*
- settings - disabled at the begining, enabled after clicking settingsOn button
- next - it enables all the buttons of type *answer*
- answers - like settings, enabled after clicking next button.

Normal button looks like this:

```
<MyButton name='next'       type="next"       check={() => this.checker("next")} toggle={this.toggler.bind(this)} />
```

Parent send toggle function and check function with parameters to child.
Only settingOn and next are enabled at beginining. It is made by App.*state*.next set to true and App.*state*.answers to false. If App.state.answers is false all the components of type answers are disabled. 
Now, everything seems to be working here however one last thing is not:
If i press button "next" it checks what is parent's state.answer and sets it to true (check console log in my pen for confirmation). However changing parent's this.state.answer to true doesnt rerender components of type answer.

To be honest i wanted to make it less messy and learn React, but it seems i could do it via jQuery in one hour a few days ago :/ Is there a good solution for my problem? Should i come back to jQuery and forget React? Or i am one step from solving the problem?
Please help!

Link to [codepen](https://codepen.io/kalreg/pen/wmjJJo?editors=0011)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a couple of things I noticed on your codepen that stood out as possible issues.

```
 onClicked(){
          this.setState = { answer:  this.props.toggle("answer") };
          // should be
          this.setState({ 
               answer: this.props.toggle("answer)
          });
    }
```

Another observation is on `componentDidMount` you're setting a default state with `this.setState({ answer: false, isActive: this.props.check("next") })`, I would move these default states to the `constructor()` as it'd avoid a rerender.

I'm not exactly sure if this is an anti-pattern or not, but I'd avoid setting/getting state like

```
 this.setState({
         [type]: !this.state[type]
         // instead use
         type: !this.state.type
     })
```

Finally I think I was able to get a working component of what you were asking, see this [codepen.io](https://codepen.io/jwalls/pen/rdvyvQ?editors=0010). Hopefully this helps, happy coding!

Comment: Your pen works exactly how i intended, now i have to dig into it and extend to more complicated way. You use some unknown for me techniques (like ES6 ...props) so need a while to understand how it really works. Anyways great thanks for your time and help.